# Problem addient gradients to a custom cell background swift

Tags: swift, uikit, cell, extension-methods

I've created a custom class to apply different gradients as you can see. But my problem is that I can't use it to add gradient to a custom cell

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    // MARK: - Creamos funcion para poder aplicar degrado vertical 2 colores
    func aplicarFondoDegradado() {
        let colorArriba =  UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 4/255, blue: 14/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorAbajo = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorArriba, colorAbajo]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
                
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
    }
    func aplicarDegradadoCultural() {
        let colorInicio =  UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 56/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorFin = UIColor(red: 125/255, green: 195/255, blue: 226/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorInicio, colorFin]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        // Set end point.
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
    }
    func aplicarDegradadoDeportes() {
        let colorInicio =  UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 56/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorFin = UIColor(red: 125/255, green: 195/255, blue: 226/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
     let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorInicio, colorFin]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
    }
}
```

And It works but my problem is that when I tried to apply to a dinamic cell the gradient it's not shown.

This is my code for the tableview controller which includes the custom cell controller:

```
import UIKit

class EventosCustomCellController: UITableViewCell {
    

    @IBOutlet weak var imEvento: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtNombreEvento: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFechaEvento: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtEstadoEvento: UILabel!
}

class ListaEventosTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Eventos"
        
        
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return eventos.contarEventos()
    }

    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototipoCeldaEvento", for: indexPath) as! EventosCustomCellController
        
        let evento = eventos.buscarEventoPorID(id: indexPath.row)
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        
        cell.txtNombreEvento?.text = evento?.nombre
        cell.txtFechaEvento?.text = evento?.fecha
        cell.txtEstadoEvento?.text = evento?.tipo
        //THE PROBLEM IS HERE THE GRADIENT IS NOT SHOWN
        //THE PROBLEM IS HERE THE GRADIENT IS NOT SHOWN
        if evento?.tipo == "deportivo"{
            cell.aplicarDegradadoCultural()}
        else if evento?.tipo == "cultural"{
            cell.aplicarFondoDegradado()            }
        else{
            cell.aplicarDegradadoDeportes()}
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
           cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
        cell.imEvento.loadFrom(URLAddress: (evento?.imagenes![0])!)
      
        cell.imEvento.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        cell.imEvento.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.imEvento.layer.borderWidth = 3
        cell.imEvento.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.white.cgColor
        return cell
    }
    

    
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
   
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let celdaPulsada = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
        eventos.devolverCeldaPulsada (id: celdaPulsada!)
    }}
```

Comment: UITableViewCell adds all subviews in `contentView`. Please try applying gradient to `contentView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a couple things wrong -- and, you'll find it ***much easier*** to use a custom "GradientView"

Cells are reused... with your `extension UIView` approach, you are inserting  **another** gradient layer every time the cell is used.

Also, you're not guaranteed to have the correct frame at that point.

Here is a very simple, basic custom "GradientView":

```
class GradientView: UIView {
    
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer!
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        gradientLayer = self.layer as? CAGradientLayer
    }
    
}
```

Add a `UIView` to your cell's `Content View` in Storyboard, behind all of the labels, and constrain it to all 4 sides.

Then, assign its Custom Class to `GradientView`, and connect it to your cell class just like the labels:

```
@IBOutlet weak var gradientView: GradientView!
```

Then, delete your `extension UIView` and move those gradient funcs to your cell, so it looks like this:

```
class EventosCustomCellController: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imEvento: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtNombreEvento: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFechaEvento: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtEstadoEvento: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var gradientView: GradientView!
    
    func aplicarFondoDegradado() {
        let colorArriba =  UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 4/255, blue: 14/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorAbajo = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        
        gradientView.gradientLayer.colors = [colorArriba, colorAbajo]
        gradientView.gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

        // start/end points
        gradientView.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gradientView.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
    }
    func aplicarDegradadoCultural() {
        let colorInicio =  UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 56/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorFin = UIColor(red: 125/255, green: 195/255, blue: 226/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        
        gradientView.gradientLayer.colors = [colorInicio, colorFin]

        // start/end points
        gradientView.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientView.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    }
    func aplicarDegradadoDeportes() {
        let colorInicio =  UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 56/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorFin = UIColor(red: 125/255, green: 195/255, blue: 226/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

        gradientView.gradientLayer.colors = [colorInicio, colorFin]

        // start/end points
        gradientView.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientView.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    }
    
}
```

Now you can keep this in `cellForRowAt`:

```
    if evento?.tipo == "deportivo" {
        cell.aplicarDegradadoCultural()
    }
    else if evento?.tipo == "cultural" {
        cell.aplicarFondoDegradado()
    }
    else {
        cell.aplicarDegradadoDeportes()
    }
```

and your cell's will set the gradient properties and size automatically.

Comment: Ok I see you point but I can't uderstand it completly. You say I minserting another gradient layer every time the cell is used but If I insert an UIView to my cell Am I not doing something similar?  and why do you say "Also, you're not guaranteed to have the correct frame at that point." I'm sure you're right about everything because I'm a noob, but please could you clarify my doubts? Thanks!!

Comment: @Monrac - with your original code, you are creating and inserting a **new** `CAGradientLayer` every time `cellForRowAt` is called. Because cells are reused as you scroll up and down, you could end up with dozens of gradient layers - and you'd only ever see the first one added. If you add the `GradientView` in Storyboard, and only set its properties (colors, start/end points, etc) each time, that view (and its gradient layer) only exists once. Just like the labels... you only set their `.text` each time, you don't create and add new ones.